# Resetting jQuery timer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, reset, countdown

I need to reset my timer back to 5 seconds. But it doesn't work. Can you help:

> ```
>   <script type="text/javascript">
>       "use strict";
>       $(document).ready(function() {      
>           $('span.countdown').countdown({seconds: 5, callback: 'alert("Test");', onExpiry: restart}); 
>       });
>
>       function restart() { 
>           $('span.countdown').countdown('change', {seconds: 5}); 
>       } 
>   </script>
> ```

Comment: Are you trying to do something every 5 seconds? Not sure what is the countdown doing, it's not a standard jQuery method AFAIK.

Comment: And how to do something every 5 seconds in JS ?

Comment: If you want to do something every 5 seconds in JS use `setInterval(yourFunction, 5000);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.elated.com/articles/javascript-timers-with-settimeout-and-setinterval/

you use `setTimeout()` for a single countdown

`setInterval()` to do something every X number of seconds

and `clearTimeout()` to reset the counter

Bojan is right in saying that this is not normal JQuery syntax, is it a plugin or something? Whatever it is it's probably little less than syntactic sugar.

and yeah the syntax is `setTimeout(function(), 5000);`

Comment: Correct, setInterval is the way to go if you like something executed every n seconds. More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setInterval